# Sending DatagramPacket by UDP

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I'm trying to send some data by UDP. This is my code:

```
public class UDP {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.42.99");
    int PORT = 2225;
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 10;
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT, inetAddress);
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    String message = "0123456789";
    buf = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

    datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    datagramPacket.setAddress(inetAddress);
    datagramPacket.setPort(PORT);

    datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
    datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(1010);
}
}
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:698)
at UDP.main(UDP.java:21)
```

Anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you need this line `byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];` ? because later you code `message.getBytes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.42.99");
    int PORT = 2225;
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 10;
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    String message = "0123456789";
    buf = message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, inetAddress, PORT);

    datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
    datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(1010);
}
```